# synchronising output into terminal between two threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, concurrency, command-line-interface

I'm working on a CLI-based chat tool using WebSockets for real-time communication. I have implemented separate threads for the receiver and sender functions to handle incoming messages and outgoing messages, respectively. However, I'm facing difficulty in synchronizing the output in the terminal so that the messages appear in the correct order, similar to a regular chat application.

```
def print_message(message, sender_username):
    global username
    print(f"{sender_username}{message}")
    print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + username + colorama.Fore.RESET, end='')


def receive_messages(sock):
    global finished
    while not finished:
        try:
            raw_message = sock.recv(1024).decode()
            print()
            raw_message = json.loads(raw_message)
            message_val = raw_message.get("Message")
            sender_username, _, message = message_val.partition(':')

            # Handle Join Message
            if raw_message.get("Message_type") == MESSAGE_TYPE_JOIN_ROOM:
                message = " is connected"

            # Handle public_key receive message
            if raw_message.get("Message_type") == MESSAGE_TYPE_PUBLIC_KEY:
                # If store already contains the key, skip this
                if store_public_key(raw_message.get("Message")):
                    continue
                message = " public key received"
                send_public_key(sock)

            if raw_message.get("Message_type") == MESSAGE_TYPE_LEAVE_ROOM:
                message = " is disconnected from room"

            if raw_message.get("Message_type") == MESSAGE_TYPE_SIMPLE_MESSAGE:
                message = decrypt_message(message)
                print_simple_message(message, sender_username)
                continue

            print_message(message, sender_username)

        except:
            print("An error occurred. Exiting.")
            finished = True
            break

def send_messages(sock):
    global finished
    while not finished:
        print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + username + colorama.Fore.RESET, end='')
        message = input()
        mes = message
        encrypt_message(sock, message)
        if mes == "exit()":
            print("You have left the room.")
            finished = True
            break


 #below code is to make two thread in connect_to_server function

        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages, args=(sock,))
        receive_thread.daemon = True  # Set as daemon thread to terminate with the main thread
        receive_thread.start()

        send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_messages, args=(sock,))
        send_thread.start()

        send_thread.join()
```

current terminal output-

```
user:~/CLI_Chat_Tool$ python3 client.py private harry
Connected to the server.
@harry:
@sam is connected
@harry:
@sam public key received
@harry:
hello
@harry:
@sam: hey
hi
@harry: @harry:hi
@harry:hi
@harry:
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when the sender and receiver threads run concurrently, the output in the terminal gets mixed up. Messages from the receiver thread might appear before the user's own messages sent through the sender thread, leading to a confusing user experience.

How to properly synchronize and print the messages in the terminal so that they appear in the correct order, just like in a normal chat application?

I have tried to brute force my mind to synchronous the printing on terminal and try chatgpt and bard for the solution, like i have tried to remove the last printed line of terminal which is not possible by chatgpt and other things.